# TweenMax scale bgImage

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

Im trying to scale a background image up, and then down again, but cant get it to work, any ideas?
It scales up the background fine, but it is like it never calls the "reverse" function ?

```
TweenMax.to(bg, 1, {
                css: {
                    scaleX: 1.5,
                    scaleY: 1.5,
                    transformOrigin: "center center",
                    onComplete: reverse,
                    onCompleteParams: [bg]
                },
                delay: 0.2,
                ease: Power3.easeInOut
            });

            function reverse(el) {
                TweenMaxto(el, 0.6, {
                    css: {
                        scaleX: 1.0,
                        scaleY: 1.0,
                        transformOrigin: "center center",
                        autoAlpha: 1,
                    },
                    ease: Power2.easeOut
                });
            }
```

Comment: you need to remove your `onComplete` and `onCompleteParams` outside your CSS object.. and there is a typo in yuor reverse function.. change `TweenMaxto` to `TweenMax.to(` .. you were missing the period `.` between TweenMax and to() .. also you can just use `scale` instead of `scaleX` and `scaleY` since both have the same values .. and you wouldnt need to include `transformOrigin` since the default is `50% %50` which is the same as `center center`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the onComplete, onCompleteParams outside the css:{} object like below,

```
 TweenMax.to(bg, 1, {
                css: {
                    scaleX: 1.5,
                    scaleY: 1.5,
                    transformOrigin: "center center"
                },
                onComplete: reverse,
                onCompleteParams: [bg],
                delay: 0.2,
                ease: Power3.easeInOut
            });

            function reverse(el) {
                alert("Sdasd");
                TweenMaxto(el, 0.6, {
                    css: {
                        scaleX: 1.0,
                        scaleY: 1.0,
                        transformOrigin: "center center",
                        autoAlpha: 1,
                    },
                    ease: Power2.easeOut
                });
            }
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/Nt7TW/)

Hope it helps.